# Does D allow separation of interface from implementation in templates?

Tags: templates, interface, implementation, d

I haven't tried D yet, but it seems like a very interesting language that has found some neat solutions to problems in C++. I'm curious, did it also make it possible to separate interface from implementation in templates? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

no any templates used are fully expanded at compile time

this means that the compiler needs to know the full code of the template making it impossible to keep it out of the `.di` files

Answer (score 2):

At some point in processing the *use* of a template, D needs *all* the information *about* the template. However, there is no reason that this information need be encode as the original source code (OTOH, as an implementation detail, all current D compiler do require that). This is a fundamental issue of any language that has templates stronger than generics. The implications of this depend on what you are trying to do.

If your interest in separation of interface and implementation is to hide the implementation (like shipping binary libraries and header files in C), then this can't be done. The closest you can get is some kind of code obfuscation system.

If, on the other hand, you are interested in avoiding the cost of reprocessing templates for each recompilation, something more general like a binary pre-compiled header format could allow the reuse of the results of the lexical, syntactic and some of the passes while compiling several other modules. In fact, that would be simpler to do with D than in C.

A third option would be link time code generation, but that has little difference from conventional linking with aggressive use of an anolog to pre-compiled headers.

Comment: The only way that the compiler could avoid needing the entire source code of a template is if it were to keep the partially compiled template in an intermediate format which was then used when instantiating the template, and no such intermediate format exists. You need the full template definition to instantiate a template. The exact same issue exists in C++. It's a fundamental problem with the fact that templates are used for generating code. export templates in C++ were the attempt to get around the problem, and it didn't work, because it's an issue which is fundamental to templates.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis: Isn't that effectively what I said? I know that's almost exactly what I was *trying* to say.

Comment: Perhaps, but that's not the way that it seemed to me. Your answer makes it sound like the fact that you need the source is just an implementation detail which may be fixed at some point, which isn't really the case. You'll always need the full source. It's just that it's theoretically possible to use a partially compiled version of that source rather than the raw source (though I doubt that it'll happen), but all of that information will always be needed regardless. Separating the interface and implementation of templates is essentially impossible.

Comment: I have to agree with Jonathan on this one, BCS, your answer isn't particularly clear.